# How we change equations in passive bandpass filters?

Tags: passive-networks, math, passive-filter, band-pass

I tried it myself, but I couldn't understand how the equation ended up in the given form. After bringing it to that form, the cutoff frequency values can be determined, but since I couldn't do that, I'm unable to find them. Can you help me with this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you point to a specific point in the derivation of this formula that you didn't understand? It'll be easier to help you this way.

Comment: And please show the specific circuit that it applies to.

Comment: Thank you for the warning, and I have also included the circuit. The part I understand is that we equate the cutoff frequency to 1/sqrt(2) and say 1/LC = wc^2 to find it. However, I'm unsure about how the denominator is transformed into a different format to determine the values of wc1 and wc2. I don't understand how it was brought into that form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just bringing the \$\frac{ω}{RC}\$ into the denominator and expanding it out. They've skipped over some algebra, so here, let me write out all the algebra for you.

We start with
$$\frac{\frac{ω}{RC}}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{LC}-ω^2\right)^2+\left(\frac{ω}{RC}\right)^2}}$$

Then, bring the numerator into the denominator to get
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\frac{RC}{ω}\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{LC}-ω^2\right)^2+\left(\frac{ω}{RC}\right)^2}} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{RC}{ω}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{LC}-ω^2\right)^2+\left(\frac{RC}{ω}\right)^2\left(\frac{ω}{RC}\right)^2}}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{RC}{ω}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{LC}-ω^2\right)^2+1}}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{RC}{LCω}-\frac{RC}{ω}ω^2\right)^2+1}}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{R}{Lω}-RCω\right)^2+1}}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1}{ω\frac{L}{R}}-ωRC\right)^2}}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(ωRC-\frac{1}{ω\frac{L}{R}}\right)^2}}
\end{align}$$

Note that the last step is valid because, even though \$(x-y)\$ is not equal to \$(y-x)\$, \$(x-y)^2\$ *is* equal to \$(y-x)^2\$.